# How do I save multiple pages of API data to an S3 file without running out of memory?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I have a Node.js app running on an AWS t2.xlarge server that pulls many pages of data from an API (ie. sales order data for a specific day) and then saves that data to a flat file on S3.  Sometimes there are thousands and thousands of pages of data and before the service is finished pulling all the data from the API, it runs out of memory and crashes.

Should I be pulling one page at a time, saving that data to S3, then appending the next page?  Can I even do append to an existing S3 file?

Comment: Why not store to file system on your EC2 instance first and then send to S3?

Comment: Save to disk instead of storing in memory!

Comment: Yup, this was the right choice.  I can't accept these comments as answers, so if you'd like to post an answer I will accept it.